# how to set IQR on seaborn box plot to 10% 90%

Tags: python, seaborn

Is it possible to set the IQR to 10%-90% for a seaborn boxplot?

I have not seen anything that discusses this in the docs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change box width from IQR to user defined in seaborn boxplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66064619/change-box-width-from-iqr-to-user-defined-in-seaborn-boxplot)

Comment: You also might be interested in drawing a [`sns.boxenplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxenplot.html)